# How to add subquery filter in fflib_SObjectSelector?

Tags: apex, financialforce

I have a custom object(`Residence__c`) which has lookup relationship to Account, Now I am trying to use FinancialForce sObjectSelector to Querry Account with Residences and have few filters on residences.

I created the first Selector for Residences

```
public class ResidenceSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {
        public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType() {
            return Residence__c.sObjectType;
        }

        public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
            return new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
                    Residence__c.Name,
                    Residence__c.Id
            };
        }
    }
```

Now creating a Selector for Account

```
public class AccountSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector {
        public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType() {
            return Account.sObjectType;
        }

        public List<Schema.SObjectField> getSObjectFieldList() {
            return new List<Schema.SObjectField>{
                   Account.FirstName,
                   Account.LastName,
                   Account.PersonBirthdate


            };
        }

        public List<Account> selectById(Set<ID> idSet) {
            return (List<Account>) selectSObjectsById(idSet);
        }

        public List<Account> selectByIdWithCurrentResidences(Set<Id> idSet){
            // Query Factory for this Selector (Account)
            fflib_QueryFactory accountQueryFactory = newQueryFactory();
            accountQueryFactory.setCondition('Id IN :idSet');          




            //Add a query sub-select via the Query Factory for the Residences

            ResidenceSelector rs = new ResidenceSelector();

            fflib_QueryFactory residenceQueryFactory = rs.newQueryFactory(false);
            residenceQueryFactory.setCondition('Is_Current__c = true');
            residenceQueryFactory.setLimit(1);


            rs.addQueryFactorySubselect(accountQueryFactory, 'Residences__r'); //Residences__r is the relationship name

            System.debug(accountQueryFactory.toSOQL());
            return (List<Account>) Database.query( accountQueryFactory.toSOQL() );

        }


    }
```

As you can see in my `residenceQueryFactory` which I got from ResidenceSelector I am adding Limit and conditions. And as its a subquery I added it to parent accountQueryFactory.

Generated SOQL:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonBirthdate, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Residences__r ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST )  FROM Account WHERE Id IN :idSet ORDER BY Name ASC NULLS FIRST
```

I expected the subquery filter and Limits to be applied on subquery, but they are not as seen in `System.debug`, Can someone point me what bit I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use a slightly different pattern to do subselects with criteria

```
public List<Account> selectByIdWithCurrentResidences(Set<Id> idSet){
    if (idSet.isEmpty()) {return new List<Account>();} // avoid burning soql on empty list
    // Query Factory for this Selector (Account)
    fflib_QueryFactory aQF = newQueryFactory()
           .setCondition('Id IN :idSet');          

    //Add a query sub-select via the Query Factory for the Residences

    fflib_QueryFactory rsQF = aQF.subSelectQuery('Residences__r')
        .selectFields(...)
        .setCondition('Is_Current__c = true')
        .setLimit(1);

    return Database.query( aQF.toSOQL());

    }
```

Comment: Never thought about this,